# iron:router syntax Layout

Tags: layout, router, iron

I am using iron router to render a template within meteor framwork, as i was following probably an outdated tutorial, it seems to me there is a change in syntaxes which i could not figure out.

layout.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
            <p>cell</p>
        </div>
            <div class="span7">
                <p>cell</p>
            </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <p>cell</p>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

index.js

```
function.setDefault ('category', null );
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate:'layout',
    yieldTemplates:{
        'products':{to:'products'},
        'cart':{to:'cart'},
        'categories':{to:'categories'}
    }
    });
Router.route(function(){

    this.route('/', layout);
    this.route('/products',{
        data:function(){
            Session.set('category',this.params.name);

    },
    template:'layout',
    path:'/:name'
    })
});
```

The following error occurs
unexpected token (1:8)

Comment: The error you are getting looks like it is being thrown by `function.setDefault` should this be `Session.setDefault`?

Comment: Thanks it worked but at the moment it only shows iron:router organise your Meteor application which i used to have before changing session into function by mistake.

Comment: What is layout in ('/', layout) is it an object declared somewhere? If you let me know I'll post a possible fix

Comment: I it was Session.setDefault as in the tutorials, but i made a mistake chaning it to function to see the effect, at the moment all i get is iron router paged displayed, what am supposed to get is three colms of cells linking to templates of corrsiponding html pages.

Comment: Layout is not defined as an object, layout shows only in the code posted in the main post.

Comment: <template name="layout">

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="span2">
    <p>cell</p>
   </div>
    <div class="span7">
     <p>cell</p>
    </div>
     <div class="span3">
      <p>cell</p>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</template>

Comment: i tried linking to other pages using {{>}} mus. but it did not work either

Comment: I think the message am getting from iron router is a change in syntax and the way to link to other pages   as shown here: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#layouts

Comment: There is more than one way to declare your route using router.route. you can either pass an object or pass a function in my answer I passed route context as an object but it can easily be a function. Try the answer and see if it works if not I can fix tonight and upload an alternative using a function (as they do in the link you gave) not an object too

Comment: Sorry made some hasty edits to it, namely changing data which is designed to return a value to your template to onBeforeAction designed for setting stuff like session vars etc when a route is called ;) you need to put the yields in your layout template too otherwise iron router doesn't know where to put your categories, cart etc templates

Answer (score 0):

Where you have Router.route and use this.route in a function, Router.route should read Router.map however this is deprecated in favour of Router.route (without the map wrapper) as below:

```
Session.setDefault ('category', null );           

Router.configure({ 
    layoutTemplate:'layout', 
    yieldTemplates:{ 
        'products':{to:'products'}, 
        'cart':{to:'cart'}, 
        'categories':{to:'categories'} 
    } 
}); 
//You will need to declare a template at the least here so it knows what to render to main area
Router.route('/', {template: "template_name"); 
Router.route('/products/:name',{ 
    onBeforeAction:function(){ 
        Session.set('category',this.params.name); 
        this.next ();
    }, 
    //you don't need this to be layout
    //as you are defining a default layout above 
    //but you will need to specify a template for the main yield area
    template:'template_name'
    // you don't need to specify path here as it will use '/products'
    //if you want to specify a route name use line below
    //,name: 'routename'
});
```

Where url would be `/products/product_name`

Where `template_name` is the template you want to render in your main `{{> yield}}`

In your layout template you need to place the following for your yields wherever you want to display them

```
{{> yield 'products'}}
{{> yield 'categories'}}
{{> yield 'cart'}}
{{> yield }} //this is the template you specify in template: 'template_name'
```

(Done from my phone so can't test but can update later if it doesn't work for you)

Comment: <template name="layout">

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="span2">
    <p>    {{> yield 'categories'}}</p>
   </div>
    <div class="span7">
     <p>{{> yield 'products'}}</p>
    </div>
     <div class="span3">
      <p>{{> yield 'cart'}}</p>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</template>  i tried this before still didn't work